# In google Sheets: is it possible to make a cell reference another sheet automatically, after you duplicate or copy/paste it?

Tags: google-sheets, duplicates, spreadsheet, copy-paste

I have a rent spreadsheet that our house uses to calculate rent/expenses every month. Every month we duplicate or copy/paste last month's rent sheet for the new month. I want that new month's sheet to reference the previous month's balance total, to carry over the renter's balance from the previous month. I would like it to automatically do this when I duplicate the sheet. (Or if I copy/paste the sheet).

Is this possible?

I have been unable to find a way to do this. It seems we have to manually copy/paste the balance column from the previous month, rather than have it be automatically referenced. It would be nice if copying of an entire sheet would retain logical relationships and be able to reference the neighbouring sheet; in the same way copying a cell retains the reference to a neighbouring cell.
Can this be done?

Comment: Please can you post a sample of your sheet, so that we can see what the different sheet names are like!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
function sheetName() {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName();
}
function previousSheetName() {
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  for (var i=0;i<sheets.length;i++){
    if (sheets[i].getName()==sheetName()){
      if (i>0) {return(sheets[i-1].getName())}else{return''}
    }
  }
}
```

then use INDIRECT